# Badge Suggestion - Two Minds

Tags: discussion, badges, badge-request

Two or more answers to the same question, each with 10 or more upvotes.

Alternately called "Two faced", "Schitzophrenic" or "Confused".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suspect you'd see gaming on CW, since it is far more common to have multiple answers (per person) on CW, and the vote scores tend to be higher. You'd probably have to exclude CW.

To be honest, I'm not sure anything extra is needed... for a non-CW posts, there is already +200 points (for 2 of 10 votes) and at least two bronze medals in the bag, and a fair chance at a tick (+15 points), and twice the chance at "enlightened" (silver) and/or "good answer" (silver, possibly twice).

Answer (score 1):

Not a bad idea. Here are a few more suggestions for the name:

- Divide and Conquer
- Pair Programming

**Devil's advocate says:** "Wouldn't this lead to "answer bloat" by tempting people to give needless multiple answers just to get the badge?"

Comment: If you can manage to give multiple answers that both score +10, you could argue that they are not needless. If there was no need for them, it is likely nobody would have voted it up.

Comment: @TheTXI: True, but people who are *trying* to get the badge may keep adding answers, some of which may be needless and simply add clutter.

Comment: I think down voting of needless answers would stop that wouldn't it?

Comment: Example of needless and clutter, also somewhat ironic http://superuser.com/questions/11995/i-just-spilt-coffee-on-my-laptop-what-should-i-do/12006#12006

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. Now I'm going to give him a populist badge for it. AND IT'S ALL YOUR FAULT

Comment: =( Was bound to happen anyways. I laughed at it myself but don't necessarily agree it belongs there.

Comment: I agree it's flippant nonsense but it's was popular, was marked community wiki from the outset so I earned nothing and the occasional humorous comment builds the community don't you think?  But it wasn't intended to encourage that sort of thing, the idea was more about people being able to develop their own ideas by posting reasonable alternatives where they weren't 100% sure how they felt.

Comment: And where's my populist badge?!  Only kidding, I believe that I need 2x the vote of the accepted answer + 1 and I'm two short.  I was within one earlier on...

Answer (score 0):

Like the idea, don't like the name (it seems to imply that there is more than one person on an answer). The other ideas are slightly better.

Since +10 will get you a Nice Answer badge, two of them in the same question should be "Twice As Nice"

Three nice answers all in one thread could be "Three's a Crowd" or "Nicely Thricely" and then after that I just stop getting concerned.

Comment: But who gets the badge? The asker? Each poster?

Comment: devinb: I was assuming we were talking about the same poster person answering the question multiple times.

Comment: oh.
Why would you do that? If it's not a CW, then you should just edit your original post.